# What is 'Bend it like Beckham?'

Tags: meaning-in-context

A very popular phrase it is `Bend it like Beckham.` I searched it on the Internet but found no satisfactory answers.They say that it's about bending a pathway of the ball like Beckham and also the rules in the life! But do you *bend a pathway* of a ball? Or you *spin it as in cricket?*

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In football (soccer), you [***bend*** or *curl*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(football)) the ball if you give it a spin to ensure that it doesn’t fly straight but curves during flight.

The movie [*Bend It Like Beckham*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bend_It_Like_Beckham)<sup>1</sup> picks up the term, based to the famous player’s ability to score with this technique. As it has become somewhat famous, the term is sometimes used as metaphor for bending the rules and expectations of society, referring to the protagonists’ determination to reach their dreams of playing professional football (soccer) as females.

---

<sup>1</sup> And in the movie title, *bend* gives a nice alliteration, which *curl* wouldn’t.

Comment: Not trying to spoil your answer, but no ball flies straight in soccer. All kicks (unless it's a ground shot) curve to some extent. The alliteration with his name is good, yes.

Comment: @Lambie yeah, but there’s curves and *curves*. ;-)